# The Dark Trails Right Across the Field

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> Finding my way I forge a new path
>     Cutting through wood with what alchemists hath
>     Fields not mountains I seek for swift passage
>     Cross this land I must to pass on my message

Who is this messenger?

---

**Hint 1:**

> The path I once took may soon be lost forever.

**Hint 2:**

> My personality's kind of split. One side tends to remember, the other tends to forget.

**Hint 3:**

> I'm a prism that has helped advance both art and science.

**Hint 4:**

> *What do alchemists have to work with in their quest?*
>  It's not the answer but should unlock one of the clues

---

UPDATES:
2019.09.30 - Minor update on title and tags to better fit the puzzle.

Comment: Can't help but ask... is the reverse acrostic of the title, ROT13(sneg'q), part of the clues?

Comment: @JMP Haha! That's just an unhappy accident and not part of the clues. I can sort of see how that could be a dark trail though xd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you are:

> A **PENCIL**?

*Finding my way I forge a new path*

> As a pencil writes on paper it creates a trail of graphite.

*Cutting through wood with what alchemists hath*

> A pencil is made of *wood* with a central graphite core running all the way through it, colloquially known as '*lead*', which is also the name of the metal alchemists attempt to turn into gold.

*Fields not mountains I seek for swift passage*

> A pencil writes more smoothly and effectively on something flat, like a field.

*Cross this land I must to pass on my message*

> To write a message the pencil must make contact with the page and move across it.

As for the title:

> The 'dark trails' are the result of writing or drawing with it.

This works with the clues too, since:

> A pencil's 'split personality' allows it to **write** with the sharpened point on one end (allowing things to be written down and 'remembered') and **delete** with the eraser on the other end (allowing it to 'forget' as words and lines are removed). This also explains how its path 'might soon be lost forever' - it could be rubbed out!
>
>  Furthermore, the invention of the pencil has assisted both science (in the writing down of ideas) and art (in drawing, etc.).

Comment: Well done! I'll award the bounty once the time constraint has passed.

Answer (score 5):

The messenger is

> a [wildfire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildfire)

## The Dark Trail Right Across the Field

> a wildfire leaves a trail of burned (dark) material

### Finding my way I forge a new path

> whether theres wood, grass or other vegetation, the fire makes a new path through it

### Cutting through wood with what alchemists hath

> Alchemists deal with elements (earth, air, **fire**, water)

### Fields not mountains I seek for swift passage

> From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildfire#Physical_properties): "They can move as fast as 10.8 kilometres per hour (6.7 mph) in forests and 22 kilometres per hour (14 mph) in grasslands

### Cross this land I must to pass on my message"

> If the wildfire front does not move, it will burn out. So to continue burning it must go on crossing the land

Comment: Nice try but probably a bit too literal. I'll add a hint soon.

Answer (score 2):

Is the messager:

> A gun

Finding my way I forge a new path.

> A gun is forged

Cutting through wood with what alchemists hath

> Gun powder?

Fields not mountains I seek for swift passage

> Straight line and fast

Cross this land I must to pass on my message

> The message is a bullet?

Comment: Nice try but incorrect. You should also be able to connect it to the title somehow.

Answer (score 0):

The messager is:

> Knowledge

Finding my way I forge a new path.

> Knowledge begets new knowledge

Cutting through wood with what alchemists hath

> Alcehemists had knowledge

Fields not mountains I seek for swift passage

> Knowledge passes through academic fields

Cross this land I must to pass on my message

> Knowledge can be lost if not passed on to others

Comment: Nice answer but unfortunately incorrect. I'll add another hint now.

Comment: @greystaff Thanks for the response. I'll have another go at it once I have time.